# Get a JSON String in Kotlin from API

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to determine the keywords that will let me access an API with a JSON Object in Kotlin. I've seen a lot of examples in Java but I am stumped on how to figure this out in Kotlin.

The API I am using is http://numbersapi.com/#random/trivia and can access the params: `text`, `number`, `found`, and `type`.

```
val apiURL = "http://numbersapi.com/random/year?json"

private fun loadRandomFact() {
        runOnUiThread {
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        val request:Request = Request.Builder()
            .url(apiURL).build()
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val json = response?.body()?.string()
                val txt = (JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("number")
                        .get("text")).toString()
                //update the ui from the ui thread
                runOnUiThread {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    //use Html class to decode html entities
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        factTv.text = Html.fromHtml(txt,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
                    } else {
                        factTv.text = Html.fromHtml(txt)
                    }
                }

            }
        })
```

I know in the `val txt` that the queries in the JSON Object (`number` and `text`) are wrong because my app crashes and I know it works with a similar API and tells me so in the LOGCAT:

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: No value for 
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:612)
```

What queries would the Kotlin JSON function take for this API? I've tried so many combinations but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Since Retrofit2, it does not come with a default converter and you need to add one.

For [GSON](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), you can do something like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

You can use it like this:
ApiInterface.kt

```
interface ApiInterface  {

    @GET("year?json")
    fun fetchFact() : Call<JsonObject>

    companion object {
        fun create() : ApiInterface {

            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl("http://numbersapi.com/random/")
                    .build().create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
val service = ApiInterface.create()

val call: Call<JsonObject> = service.fetchFact()
call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<JsonObject> {

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject>, response: Response<JsonObject>) {
         val response = response.body()
         Log.d("Sample",response.toString())
         Log.d("Sample", "Text: "+response!!.get("text").toString())
         // rest of the keys...
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject>, t: Throwable) {
         Log.d("Sample",t.message)
    }
})
```

Reference: https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/simple-http-with-retrofit-2-droidcon-nyc-2015?slide=67

**Note:**
This is not the only method to do but I was able to fetch data from the URL you provided.

[Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/): Check the converters section for using other converters

Hope it helps.